# Why isn't tensorflow/models not part of the TensorFlow API? Python module?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The repository https://github.com/tensorflow/models has a lot of useful functionality such as its [MNIST loading module](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/mnist/dataset.py). However, I don't think any of the code is exposed as part of the public Python TensorFlow interface.

Why is it not part of the public API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a sensible to me. These are examples where the TensorFlow library has been used in order to solve a specific problem/example.

It makes sense that the code used to solve these problems should be entirely separate from the main library/framework API, no?

ALthough, if you are specifically interested in loading the NIST dataset note that there's now an example dataset available under the `keras` api:

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

Comment: I understand you point; however, the repo has a lot of code that is not specific to a specific problem/example. 
Addressing your point about the keras API, the models repo has better mnist loading functionality than the keras API.

Comment: I think you are right, @Stwart_R. Maybe the effort of having to push code to another repo controlled by another team lead to reusable code being buried in the models repo instead of somewhere more useful.